# Spring AOP Pointcut not called

Tags: spring, aspectj, spring-aop

i work with JSF 2.2 + Spring framework 3.2.4

So, i have this applicationContent.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
      xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
      xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
      xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
      xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.2.xsd 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="true" />
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
    <context:annotation-config/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.vulcan.controller" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.vulcan.service" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.vulcan.dao" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.vulcan.spring.aop" />

.....
```

Then i have aspect component 
in

```
package com.vulcan.spring.aop;

@Aspect
public class LoggingService {
    private Log log = LogFactory.getLog(this.getClass());

    @Pointcut("execution(* *.*(..))")
    protected void loggingOperation() {}

    @Before("loggingOperation()")
    public void logJoinPoint()
    {
        System.out.println ("Hello");
     }
   ....
```

With this type of execution i assume this pointcut will be triggered on every methods. But the problem is, this pointcut isn't triggered ? Any idea why ? Thanks

FYI, i using glassfish 4, and when i deploy my web app i didn't receive any error configuration. So i assume my configuration is fine.

Comment: Spring AOP only advises public methods. Is your advice at least triggered for those, or for no methods at all?

Comment: i already try the public method e.x in loginController with (@Controller annotated). I try to invoke public method doLogin() {return string} via jsf page, and it still has no response

Comment: Small comment on your xml configuration `<context:annotation-config />` is already implied by the use of `<context:component-scan ... />`. The `base-package` attribute of component-scan can contain a comma separated list of packages to scan, so instead of 4 elements use one and put a comma separated list of packages in there. Saves you some xml.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`@Aspect` annotate classes aren't automatically detected by Spring and because it isn't detected it isn't known to the `<aop:aspectj-autoproxy />` beans. So basically there is no aspect.

Either add `@Component` to your `@Aspect` annotated class(es) so that Spring can detect and use the aspect.

```
@Compopnent
@Aspect
public class LoggingService { ... }
```

or declare the aspect explictly in your xml file

```
<bean class="LoggingService" />
```

Either way the aspect will be picked up by the `<aop:aspectj-autoproxy />` beans and the advice will be run.

Comment: annotating @Aspect in spring boot is necessary

Answer (score -3):

Try using `execution(* *(..))`.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but still not working.Btw, i'm using servlet Filter in web.xml. Is that cause this issue ?

Comment: No, that doesn't cause this issue. I modified the answer. Check out.